# Why is it when I take 3 array values it shows error but when I only show 1 value it works?

Tags: php, laravel

When I use `var_dump($paid)` it will show all the values
this is the code. If I use all 3 `description, amount, and payment_type` it will show an error that the amount is undefined. But if I use only 1 like for example I use only the `description` and erase the rest the code will work

```
$paid = array();
        foreach ( $user as $u ) :
            $paidDetail = \App\PaymentTransaction::where('user_id','=', $u->user_id)->get();
            if ($paidDetail->count()) :
                $paid[]['description'] = $paidDetail[0]->description;
                $paid[]['amount'] = $paidDetail[0]->amount;
                $paid[]['payment_type'] = $paidDetail[0]->payment_type;
            endif;  
        endforeach;

    return $paid;
```

this is for the view/blade to show the details in the frontend

```
{{ $paid['description'] }}
{{ $paid['amount'] }}
{{ $paid['payment_type'] }}
```

showing each 1 of them works but showing all of them at the same time will show an error saying that the 2nd value is undefined

Below is the var_dump($paid)

> array(1) { ["description"]=> string(33) "Plan Subscription Payment for PRO" }
>   array(1) { ["amount"]=> float(350) }
>   array(1) { ["payment_type"]=> string(27) "Stripe Payment Subscription" }
>   array(1) { ["description"]=> string(38) "Test Plan Subscription Payment for PRO" }
>   array(1) { ["amount"]=> float(351) }
>   array(1) { ["payment_type"]=> string(27) "Stripe Payment Subscription" }

Comment: can you show the output of var_dump($paid)

Comment: you have an array like `$paid[][]` you should use it like this

Comment: @sumit I've updated the question please check if you have time

Comment: @Webdesigner I also tried that. It shows an error something about missing value inside [ ]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$paid = array();
$i=0;

foreach ( $user as $u ) :
    $paidDetail = \App\PaymentTransaction::where('user_id','=', $u->user_id)->get();
    if ($paidDetail->count()) :
        $paid[$i]['description'] = $paidDetail[0]->description;
        $paid[$i]['amount'] = $paidDetail[0]->amount;
        $paid[$i]['payment_type'] = $paidDetail[0]->payment_type;
        $i++;
    endif;
endforeach;

return $paid;
```

The main issue with you code is that you forgot to use a index on you array. Adding `$i` as an index makes sure that each user payment have his own index.

#### Note

Lopping thru an collection and doing a SQL QUERY for each user is not wrong but also not a good practice. Try to get both in one SQL Statment.

Comment: Okay I got it. The 2nd block is not need it will only be `{{ $paid['description'] }}
    {{ $paid['amount'] }}
    {{ $paid['payment_type'] }}`

Comment: You have not explained what have you modified in the code. Should we compare both your code and the OP code?

Comment: @Webdesigner Please edit your answer a little bit so that the downvote can be removed.

Comment: I hope my edit will explain my code for dose how don't get it right away

Answer (score 0):

It's just because,

Your **foreach loop** overwriting **0 Index** Parameters and every time last record stores in Array.

And Executing query in every iteration of foreach loop may reduce your code performance.

You Should use laravel eloquent model and relationship for this issue.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)